# Memory manipulation: set every n-th bit (C/C++) in modern CPUs/GPUs

Tags: c, bitmap, sse

As far as I understood, "modern" CPUs have quite impressive routines to manipulate binary data, like streaming many data through the same operation.

Ad hoc I can not find a lib to make simple instructions (set every 5th bit in a GB of Memory) using those CPU or GPU hardware, just the classical `| << &` tricks.

But setting every 5th or 721th bit must be the same like painting a vertical black line in a black&white picture of width 5 or width 721, and I would expect there to be a fast way for that.

So my question: Is there any hint how to play with bits in a fast and efficient way on Mainstream x86_64 Intel/AMD CPU or GPU? Open Source would be a side condition.

Comment: Depends on your definition of fast. Doing this requires writing to every single byte in that GB of memory, which will be entirely limited by main memory bandwidth. There's no way round that...

Comment: You might be able to use the [x86 vector intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/c/8/e/18072-347603.pdf) to manipulate large (128- or 256-bit) chunks of RAM at once, but it's still going to be a load-manipulate-store loop.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: At least I thought to reduce the number of instructions used: avoid manually stepping into every byte, but performing bigger operations alike memcopy.

Comment: You might find that simply writing your code in C or C++ and compiling it with either `clang` or a recent `gcc` will do a fairly good job of optimising for vector units.

Comment: @flaschenpost: Reducing the number of instructions used isn't going to help performance, because the CPU core is significantly faster than the channel to main memory.

Comment: @caf But doing one CPU- or GPU- optimized command (which could work for a whole cache line) should be faster than processing byte by byte, and I thought that painting a line on b&w is a real basic GPU-command.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, doing this for huge chunks of memory is going to be bottlenecked by cache misses.  Current CPUs can do quite a few instructions per load/store and still max out memory bandwidth.  The problem is much more interesting if we're talking about a few k of memory that's already in L1 cache.

If you're setting every 721st bit, vector stuff won't help you.  Your stride is 90.125 bytes, which is bigger than even AVX512 vectors.  So the optimal solution is to do a single byte `OR` at the appropriate address.  Writing the loop to keep track of the bit-position within the byte, and the byte position, is non trivial.  If it's a compile-time constant stride, unrolling by 8 would make it easy.  (An extra increment of one byte every 8th `OR`.)

```
; pointer in rdi
; loop counter in ecx
.loop:
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*0],  1<<0
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*1],  1<<1
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*2],  1<<2
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*3],  1<<3
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*4],  1<<4
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*5],  1<<5
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*6],  1<<6
    or byte ptr [rdi+90*7],  1<<7
    add rdi, 90*8 + 1
    sub ecx, 8
    jg .loop
    ; handle the last up to 7 iterations
```

For strides that aren't a compile-time constant, you could rotate an 8-bit register by `stride % 8` while doing `ptr += stride/8 + carry`.  Actually, rotate by a count-from-a-register is a bit slower than usual ALU ops (on recent Intel), but so is variable-count shift.

```
; ecx = unsigned int stride.  rdi=char *dest
mov  ebx, ecx
and  ecx, 7    ; ecx = stride%8
shr  ebx, 3    ; ebx = stride/8

mov  al, 1
.loop:
    or    byte ptr [rdi], al
    rol   al, cl
    add   rdi, rbx
    ;  efficiently figure out when we need to add an extra 1 to rdi
    ; lost interest at this point, feel free to edit or post another answer finishing this code.
    dec   edx
    jg   .loop
```

I'm trying to think of a way to increment the bit-within-byte position that sets the carry flag when it wraps, so you can `adc` to do `ptr+= stride + carry`.  Or else just get a 0 or 1 to add.

### shorter stride

If your bit stride is equal to 128b, things are trivial.  Just read/modify and store with a constant mask to `POR`.

If your stride is smaller, then things get interesting.  There isn't a bitwise-rotate instruction for vector registers.  Shifting multiple set bits in an xmm register might be possible with something clever.